# Alternative proof of 2.36 Rudin... alternative or flawed proof?

Tags: general-topology, compactness, alternative-proof, fake-proofs

### Theorem:

If $\{K_α\}$ is a collection of compact subsets of a metric space $X$ such that the intersection of every finite subcollection of $\{K_α\}$ is nonempty, then $⋂_α K_α$ is nonempty.

### What I think is a fake proof:

I've found this proof on the [last comment of a post from a concurrent website](https://mathhelpforum.com/t/theorem-from-baby-rudin-thm-2-36.168032/). I think it is flawed since between $(2)$ and $(3)$ he assumes $X$ is compact...

Here it goes:

> Suppose that $$⋂_{α∈A}K_α=∅ \tag{1}$$
> then by DeMorgan's law we get that $$⋃_{α∈A}(X\backslash K_α)=X \tag{2}$$
> but since the $K_α$
> are closed we see that $X\backslash K_α$
> are open and so by compactness there exists some finite subcover $X\backslash K_{α_1},⋯,X\backslash K_{α_n}$
> but $$⋃_{j=1...n}(X\backslash K_{α_j})=X \tag{3}$$
> implies, once again by DeMorgan's law, that $$⋂_{j=1...n}K_{α_j}=∅ \tag{4}$$
> contradicting the FIP of $\{K_α\}_{α∈A}$
> .

What do you think? Is this proof accurate?

PS: I already have a proof of this result, but I am curious about this alternative proof.

Comment: It is an error, but by replacing $X$ with one of the $K_\alpha$ it can be fixed.

Comment: ^ and I guess you already know this though, since if I recall correctly, that is exactly how Rudin proves the theorem.

Comment: @BrianMoehring Your comment could be an answer